# Run a pre build step only once in solution. Dot NET Core

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-target

Is there a way to run a prebuild build target only once per solution build.

I want this target to build if any project in the solution is built.
I would really prefer if this target can be kept in a directory build targets file.

Also is there a way to configure to run this target only in local development environment and not in CI environment?

Comment: Have a look into Singleton pattern. Create a method to run a powershell script that initiates a build for your target, call this method inside your Singleton constructor. Just an idea, might be a far more elegant solution to this if you look around.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. But, I am looking for a clean solution or a right way to do this. This could very well be a designed use case.

Comment: Goodluck! Hopefully you could come back and post your findings if you get to it before anyone else :)